# How would i retrieve relation data through Make?

Tags: make.com, notion

I'm new to automation and all i'm trying to do is create a google calendar event with specific details when I create a new "Job" in a notion Database

I tried using Zapier but that didn't seem to work but Make seemed more promising,
There is only 2 tables call Job Tracker & Clients, the relation data im trying to get is the "location" and "Name" from clients through the Job Tracker Database.

I've tried different modules but I have a feeling i may have not use correctly as like i said, i'm new but have been trying for a couple hours to get it to work by mixing and trying different modules but still nothing happens.

I've looked through the manuals and tried searching "How to access relation data through Notion with Make" and also tried rewording but all that shows up is how to create relation in notion through Make/Zapier which doesn't seem to relevant.

Any thoughts or guidance is much appreciated

- Grim

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Zapier, I think it can be done with the "New Database Item" trigger in Notion, then a lookup from the other notion database, then the "Create event" action in Google Calendar. But it sounds like you tried that already and it didn't work.

If you're open to trying Relay.app (disclaimer: I work there), we can definitely help you set this up.

Comment: Hiya, how would i go about this using your site?